# Use the definition of limit to show that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (5,4)} 2x^2 -3y^2 = 2$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

For any $\epsilon > 0$, I want to show that $|2x^2 -3y^2-2|< \epsilon$ whenever

$0<\sqrt{(x-5)^2 + (y-4)^2}< \delta$.

What I've tried so far is expanding out the argument in the absolute value to get:

$|2x^2-20x +20x +50 - 50 -3y^2 +24y -24y + 48 -48-2|$ so that I can get

$|2(x-5)^2 -3(y-4)^2 +20x -24y -100|$.

I could use the triangle inequality to get that

$|2(x-5)^2 -3(y-4)^2 +20x -24y -100| \le |2(x-5)^2 -3(y-4)^2| +|20x -24y -100|$ and use the triangle inequality again to get

$|2(x-5)^2 -3(y-4)^2| +|20x -24y -100| \le |2(x-5)^2| + |3(y-4)^2| +|20x -24y -100|$ so that I could possibly do

$|2(x-5)^2| + |3(y-4)^2| +|20x -24y -100|< 2\delta^2 + 3\delta^2 + |20x -24y -100|$

But I'm not sure how to proceed from there. It would be helpful if someone could possibly point out a better method? That, or help with possible next steps?

Comment: Sigh, what useless busy work.  As the function is continuous, the limit at (5,4) is 2×5×5 - 3×4×4 = 50 - 48.

Comment: I'm supposed to use the definition of limit

Comment: Then use it to show the limit at a of a continuous function f is f(a) and note how that problem is a simple application of your work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make $\delta <1$,

\begin{align}
|2x^2-3y^2-2| &= |2(x-5+5)^2-3(y-4+4)^2-2|\\
&=|2[(x-5)^2+10(x-5)+25]-3[(y-4)^2+8(y-4)+16]-2|\\
&=|2(x-5)^2+20(x-5)-3(y-4)^2-24(y-4)| \\
&\le 2\delta^2 + 20 \delta +3\delta^2+24 \delta \\
&\le 49 \delta
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$|2x^2-3y^2-50+48|=|2(x^2-25)-3(y^2-16)|\leq2|x-5||x+5|+3|y-4||y+4|$$
also
$$|x-5|<\sqrt{(x-5)^2 + (y-4)^2}< \delta$$
$$|y-4|<\sqrt{(x-5)^2 + (y-4)^2}< \delta$$

Comment: I was wondering how we're able to show that $|x+5|<\delta$? We can say that $|x-5|< \delta$ for sure, but what if $|x+5|>\delta?$

Comment: $x+5<\delta+10$

Comment: So we can do $|x+5|<|\delta + 10|$ since we can assume that $x$ is very close to $5$, and so both sides of the inequality are positive? And also we assume that $\delta < 1$?